# Finding mathematical objects

Tags: recreational-mathematics, online-resources, art

I am very interested in mathematical art/object such as Moebius strip, Klein bottle, etc. and I am searching a place/website where we can buy such things. Does anyone know where I can find something like this ? Thank you!

Comment: Cliff Stoll is a start. https://www.kleinbottle.com/

Comment: A search for _mathematical art_ leads to many links.

Comment: I imagine that many MSE people will have the same initial gut feel as me: this question is off-topic and easily answered by a Google search. Can we agree to suppress our initial reactions, and support the question so as to support people making mathematical art?

Comment: [This shop](https://www.shapeways.com/shops/bathsheba) on Shapeways has many mathematical objects which you can order to be 3D printed.